# Optimizating Prime Number Sequence

Tags: c++, algorithm, analysis

I am stuck on a questions from Codechef practice problems difficulty medium with problem statement:

> Shridhar wants to generate some prime numbers for his cryptosystem.
>   Help him! Your task is to generate all prime numbers between two given
>   numbers

[Rest of the description, I/O format, Test cases examples on this question link](https://www.codechef.com/problems/PRIME1)

The problem with my implementation is getting a TLE (Time Limit Exceeded) and wish to solve this problem, can you point out any problem in my implementation, I can't seem to figure it out after hours of dry run.

Includes, Directives and ifPrime function

```
#include<map>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#define LLD long long int
#define REPNE(i,a,b) for(LLD i=a; i<=b; ++i)
#define REPNEI(i,a,b,k) for(LLD i=a; i<=b; i+=k)
using namespace std;

map<LLD, bool> mem;

bool ifPrime ( LLD a ) {
    if ( a<2 ) return false;
    else if ( a==2 ) return true;
    else if ( a%2==0 ) return false;

    REPNEI(i,3,sqrt(a),2) {
        if ( a%i==0 ) return false;
    }

    mem[a] = true;
    return true;
}
```

Generate Prime Function

```
void genPrime ( LLD a, LLD b ) {
    REPNE(i,a,b) {
        if ( mem.find(i) != mem.end() ) printf("%lld\n", i);
        else if ( ifPrime(i) ) printf("%lld\n", i);
    } printf("\n");
}
```

Main

```
int main ( ) {
    // freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);

    int t; scanf("%d", &t);
    REPNE(test, 1, t) {
        LLD a, b;
        scanf("%lld %lld", &a, &b);

        genPrime(a,b);

    }
}
```

I can't think of another solution to this problem, the only way I came up is memoization, and it is also handling large integers as well. Help needed.

Comment: Do you really consider `REPNE` more readable than simple loop ?

Comment: You may use [Sieve_of_Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Comment: people into competitive programming find macros easier than writing complete loops because speed really does matter in competitions, where as in actual live development, these should be avoided to ensure readability among team members @Jarod42

Comment: It is not faster to execute, it is not faster to compile. faster to write maybe, but time spend would be to find correct algorithm. You don't have a lot to write...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach has a problem that it is generating memoization key, value pairs. Probably they should be tested immediately instead of saving them.

An easy solution is to iterate over the range `m<=x<=n` and then check if the number is prime using the optimized prime checker algorithm which takes around (O((n-m)^1/2)), which is quiet less for very large numbers.

Prime function

```
bool ifPrime ( int n ) {
    if ( n==2 ) return true;
    else if ( n%2==0 || n<=1 ) return false;
    for ( int i=3; i<=sqrt(n); i+=2 ) {
        if ( n%i==0 ) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

and you main as

```
int main ( ) {
    int t; scanf("%d", &t);
    REPNE(test, 1, t) {
        LLD a, b;
        scanf("%lld %lld", &a, &b);

        REPNE(i,a,b) {
            if ( ifPrime(i) ) printf("%lld\n", i);  
        } printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I've tried to code according to your macro definitions, hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks alot! This implementation works perfectly and is quiet easy to comprehend, plus the codechef judge gave this solution an Accepted answer for all cases +1

Comment: ...given that the compiler optimizes the repeated calls to sqrt(n) away...

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to use std::unordered_map instead of std::map. Often std::map is implemented with trees and std::unordered_map with hash tables. Operations on hash tables are normally faster on modern computers than operations on trees.